# Не работает autoprefixer (express, node-sass-middleware, postcss-middleware)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, autoprefixer

Репозиторий: https://bitbucket.org/Oliver_Patterson/salary-info/src

Пытаюсь разобраться с модулями, никак не могу заставить работать `autoprefixer`, что я делаю не так?

---

После установки `postcss-middleware` в консоли было это:

> found 1 low severity vulnerability   run `npm audit fix` to fix them,
> or `npm audit` for details
>
> ```
>                    === npm audit security report ===
>
>
>                              Manual Review
>          Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve
>
>       Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance
> ```
>
> Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service
>
> Package         braces
>
> Patched in      >=2.3.1
>
> Dependency of   postcss-middleware
>
> Path            postcss-middleware > vinyl-fs > glob-stream >
> micromatch >
> braces
>
> More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/786

После попытки `npm audit fix`:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2
> (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
> Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted
> {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> up to date in 8.261s
>
> 20 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 525 scanned packages   1 vulnerability
> required manual review and could not be updated

`npm audit`

> ```
>                    === npm audit security report ===
>
>
>                              Manual Review
>          Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve
>
>       Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance
> ```
>
> Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service
>
> Package         braces
>
> Patched in      >=2.3.1
>
> Dependency of   postcss-middleware
>
> Path            postcss-middleware > vinyl-fs > glob-stream >
> micromatch >
> braces
>
> More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/786
>
> found 1 low severity vulnerability in 525 scanned packages   1
> vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.

Comment: npm i --save postcss@latest

Comment: Все тоже самое и та же "ошибка".

Comment: Как я понял, проблема в fsevents, оно не поддерживают мою систему.

Comment: попробуйте установить пакет с флагом --no-optional

Comment: Я правильно понял? `npm i --save postcss@latest --no-optional`

Comment: Да, если возникнет ошибка - сбросьте сюда

Comment: # npm i --save postcss@latest --no-optional
+ postcss@8.2.10
updated 1 package and audited 525 packages in 13.756s

20 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: пакет установился, найдена 1 уязвимость. Приведите вывод команды npm audit

Comment: В комментарии не получилось из-за превышения лимита, я добавил в конец вопроса.

Comment: В зависимостях у postcss-middleware есть пакет braces уязвленной версии. Вы с этим ничего не сделаете, если только не установите bracers более высокой версии, но не факт, что будет 100% совместимость. Можно создать issue на github для разработчиков postcss-middleware, что бы использовали более свежий пакет, опять же, не факт, что такого issue уже нет)

Comment: Насколько я помню, последние обновления у `postcss-middleware` были 3 года назад, гиблое дело?

Comment: Возможно) Не вижу активности от автора репы в последних issue)

Comment: Что тогда можно придумать? Чем можно заменить?

Comment: опять же, никто Вам не мешает форкнуть postcss, postcss-middleware, сделать необходимые изменения и использовать свой форк) Но, конечно, поддерживать так-же Вам самостоятельно придется его) не рекомендовал бы, если у Вас промышленное приложение)

Comment: Как тогда лучше поступить? Мне желателен авто префиксер (не хочется компилировать scss файл через что-то другое, дабы были префиксы). На что можно заменить?

Comment: Можете и этот использовать, опять же, если у Вас не промышленное решение, а изучение/пет-проект, иначе подыскать что-то поновее. Пакеты подсказать не смогу

Comment: А по поводу "Заставить работать", не увидел у Вас в проекте Gulp(webpack), Вам нужно прочитать секцию Usage по ссылке, что бы заставить работать https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer

Comment: Я пытался сделать по этому примеру: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-middleware#connect-with-other-middleware-example

Comment: Я вот все думаю.. Есть ли смысл использовать webpack, если это все будет использоваться в проектах в основном с маленькой страничкой, точнее где будет один .css файл и один .js (маленького размера)?